# Why is screen not background surface does not blit onto screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I am a beginner in pygame and I have been learning how to create a Flappy Bird game. I found a image shown below in the `FlappyBird/assets` folder.

[image: Flappy bird background]

After doing so, I added code to show the image onto a screen:

```py
# Pygame flappy bird program
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((288, 512))
bg_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/background-day.png').convert()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.blit(bg_surface, (0, 0))
```

But it ended up showing part of the screen, shown as follows:

[image]

Why is that? Any help or comments on my code will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it due to the slow rendering of it? I dragged the window up and down the screen, and discovered each time I dragged the window, the image reveals more. At a certain level, it stops.

Comment: You're not flushing the changes to the window.  Add a `pygame.display.flip()` after the `screen.blit(`

Comment: You missed to update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will try it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((288, 512))
bg_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/background-day.png').convert()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(bg_surface, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

You are actually drawing on a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object. If you draw on the *Surface* associated to the PyGame display, this is not immediately visible in the display. The changes become visibel, when the display is updated with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

See [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

> This will update the contents of the entire display.

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)